# Limiting the visibility of the selection|ListView

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I have a ListView inside a Column:

```
SizedBox(width: 100, height: 100, child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: _listHours.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Center(child: Text(_listHours[index].toString())),
              selected: index == _selectedIndexHours,
              dense: true,
              selectedTileColor: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(0.6),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndexHours = _listHours[index];
                });
              },
            );
          }
      ),),
```

When an item is selected, the selection itself is visible by scrolling the entire length of the screen.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a problem similar to [this one](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73315) where the ListTile's decoration renders outside the ListView. There is no solution for this yet but you can implement some workarounds. In this section of code, I set on "null" the ListTile's "onTap" parameter and wrapped it with a **GestureDetector** widget. Like this:

```
SizedBox(width: 100, height: 100, child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: _listHours.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndexHours = _listHours[index];
            });
          }
          child: ListTile(
          title: Center(child: Text(_listHours[index].toString())),
          selected: index == _selectedIndexHours,
          dense: true,
          selectedTileColor: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(0.6),
          onTap: null
        )
      );
    }
  ),
),
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me(